# What do the values mean in surface reflectance/surface temperature bands Landsat 8/9 OLI/TIRS C2 Level 2?

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, digital-image-processing, land-surface-temperature

I am trying to make a heat risk index using Landsat8 but I am having a bit of trouble with understanding the basics or operating remotely sensed imagery. I downloaded the band 10 of Landsat 8 because it is described to represent the surface temperature in degrees Kelvin.

I got it from EarthExplorer.

image says it has a minimum of 30106 and maximum of 55360. Are these still in digital numbers? radiance values?

[image: Screenshot of metadata]

[image: Screenshot of band descriptions]
Does the conversion rate in image 2 mean that I have to perform the raster calculation before getting into the temperature values in degrees Kelvin?